# Read Android Framebuffer in Java or Native Code

Tags: android, screenshot

first off: I know that this worky *only on rooted devices* and i *know* that it is *not* recommended - but I still want and need to do it.

I am writing an app which performs OCR on an **other** app, parses its on-screen output and gives the user feedback on the apps progress (therefor using getRootView is out of the question).

This can not be done in an other way, I *need* to have screenshots of the app at least 3 to 4 times per second.

Other ways that I tried:

- /system/bin/screencap - too slow, takes >2 sec per shot on a Galaxy S5.
- using obscure C Code to access the internal API of the SurfaceComposer (bloated, did not compile)

What I want: Have a way to read bytes from the framebuffer without having to write it to a file each time.

Currently I have the problem that my app does not have the right permissions. I added the READ_FRAME_BUFFER permission, but I still get a ERRNO 13 (Permission denied) when reading /dev/graphics/fb0, as the app itself is not started with root permissions.

I know I can start a shell or something similar with su, but that is not convenient - I would prefer a way to start a Service or my native Code with the right permissions.
I read about System Services but could not find any "easy" introductions. My experience in C/C++/Java is more than enough, but the Android API's jungle is newfound land to me.

The information from [TI-Wiki - Writing System Services](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService) seems to implie that a rebuild of the Android System is necessary to integrate a System Service. That would be out of the question. Is that correct?

In an ideal world I would have:

```
Bitmap Service.getCurrentFrame() {
    read one frame from /dev/graphics/fb0
    create Java Bitmap
    return Bitmap
}
```

This could be either native or Java code.
But how to gain the privileges?
Any ideas?

Additionally, I read that using the framebuffer is not recommended since it is about to be removed in future releases (sorry, lost source link).
What other fast ways are there to get the current screen content?

Answer (score 0):

Use DDMS lib /dev/graphics/fb0 to get bitmap. No special permission needed.